# How to Convert NA values to blank string in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R. Is there a quick way to replace all of the NA values in the dataframe with a blank string in dplyr?

```
data <- structure(list(Bank = c("Primary Residential Mortgage Loans", 
"FNB", "BWHK", "NED", "STD", "Average", "Non-Primary Residential Mortgage Loans", 
"FNB", "BWHK", "NED", "STD", "Average"), `Q3 2021` = c(NA, 88.3, 
66.5, 87.07, 97.97, 84.96, NA, 11.7, 33.5, 12.93, 2.03, 15.04
), `Q4 2021` = c(NA, 88.43, 66.71, 87.57, 98, 85.18, NA, 11.57, 
33.29, 12.43, 2, 14.82), `Q1 2022` = c(NA, 88.67, 66.6, 89.25, 
97.9, 85.61, NA, 11.33, 33.4, 10.75, 2.1, 14.39), `Q2 2022` = c(NA, 
88.84, 66.67, 89.18, 97.91, 85.65, NA, 11.16, 33.33, 10.82, 2.09, 
14.35), `Q3 2022` = c(NA, 89.09, 66.77, 88.96, 97.98, 85.7, NA, 
10.91, 33.23, 11.04, 2.02, 14.3), `Q-o-Q % Point Change` = c(NA, 
0.25, 0.1, -0.22, 0.07, 0.05, NA, -0.25, -0.1, 0.22, -0.07, -0.05
), `Y-o-Y % Point Change` = c(NA, 0.79, 0.27, 1.89, 0.01, 0.74, 
NA, -0.79, -0.27, -1.89, -0.01, -0.74)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: That would also require changing all your numeric columns to character class. Are you sure that's what you want? Why?

Comment: Why do you need that? Or do you want to print the NA as blank when you view your data?

Comment: @GregorThomas I am going to print the dataframe as a table (in kableExtra). So I don't want the NA's in my table

Comment: You’re probably better off setting `knitr.kable.na = ""` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626461/hiding-nas-when-printing-a-dataframe-in-knitr/40795577#40795577).

Comment: I thought that might be it. Generally try to avoid changing your data classes for table presentation - the table functions themselves have format and NA functionality built-in.  I'd recommend using `knitr.kable.na` as zephryl suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::replace_na()` within `dplyr::mutate(across())`. You’ll also have to coerce each column to character or `replace_na()` will throw an error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~ replace_na(as.character(.x), "")))
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 8
   Bank                  Q3 20…¹ Q4 20…² Q1 20…³ Q2 20…⁴ Q3 20…⁵ Q-o-Q…⁶ Y-o-Y…⁷
   <chr>                 <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 Primary Residential … ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""     
 2 FNB                   "88.3"  "88.43" "88.67" "88.84" "89.09" "0.25"  "0.79" 
 3 BWHK                  "66.5"  "66.71" "66.6"  "66.67" "66.77" "0.1"   "0.27" 
 4 NED                   "87.07" "87.57" "89.25" "89.18" "88.96" "-0.22" "1.89" 
 5 STD                   "97.97" "98"    "97.9"  "97.91" "97.98" "0.07"  "0.01" 
 6 Average               "84.96" "85.18" "85.61" "85.65" "85.7"  "0.05"  "0.74" 
 7 Non-Primary Resident… ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""     
 8 FNB                   "11.7"  "11.57" "11.33" "11.16" "10.91" "-0.25" "-0.79"
 9 BWHK                  "33.5"  "33.29" "33.4"  "33.33" "33.23" "-0.1"  "-0.27"
10 NED                   "12.93" "12.43" "10.75" "10.82" "11.04" "0.22"  "-1.89"
11 STD                   "2.03"  "2"     "2.1"   "2.09"  "2.02"  "-0.07" "-0.01"
12 Average               "15.04" "14.82" "14.39" "14.35" "14.3"  "-0.05" "-0.74"
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`Q3 2021`, ²​`Q4 2021`, ³​`Q1 2022`,
#   ⁴​`Q2 2022`, ⁵​`Q3 2022`, ⁶​`Q-o-Q % Point Change`, ⁷​`Y-o-Y % Point Change`
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` **function**:

First we have to transfor all columns to character type (we do it with `lapply`). Then assign `""` to data:

```
na_blank <- function(df) {
  df[] <- lapply(df[], as.character)
  df[is.na(df)] <- ""
  return(df)
  }

na_blank(data)
```

```
 Bank              `Q3 2021` `Q4 2021` `Q1 2022` `Q2 2022` `Q3 2022`
   <chr>             <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
 1 Primary Resident… ""        ""        ""        ""        ""       
 2 FNB               "88.3"    "88.43"   "88.67"   "88.84"   "89.09"  
 3 BWHK              "66.5"    "66.71"   "66.6"    "66.67"   "66.77"  
 4 NED               "87.07"   "87.57"   "89.25"   "89.18"   "88.96"  
 5 STD               "97.97"   "98"      "97.9"    "97.91"   "97.98"  
 6 Average           "84.96"   "85.18"   "85.61"   "85.65"   "85.7"   
 7 Non-Primary Resi… ""        ""        ""        ""        ""       
 8 FNB               "11.7"    "11.57"   "11.33"   "11.16"   "10.91"  
 9 BWHK              "33.5"    "33.29"   "33.4"    "33.33"   "33.23"  
10 NED               "12.93"   "12.43"   "10.75"   "10.82"   "11.04"  
11 STD               "2.03"    "2"       "2.1"     "2.09"    "2.02"   
12 Average           "15.04"   "14.82"   "14.39"   "14.35"   "14.3"   
# … with 2 more variables: `Q-o-Q % Point Change` <chr>,
#   `Y-o-Y % Point Change` <chr>
```